Storing text data from python web scrape
So I have scraped the information that I want but I don't know how to store it. So, I can manipulate it and clean it. It's one long string either I would like to store it in a csv file or a database such as SQLite or MySQLenter image description here
I just don't know if a database is easier or a csv file to add to a database

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As you need to manipulate the data, it's better to save it into database, such as SQLite or Mysql etc.
If you want to store into text file, it's better to use jsonl.
